# Are downvoted questions/answers closed or removed?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes, moderation

Questions with many downvotes are removed or closed automatically from listings and search results? Are the moderators notified?

Comment: Questions are never closed automatically. A moderator or users with enough rep have to vote to close them. They are then only actually deleted when moderators or 10k+ users vote to delete them which is actually a soft delete (makes them not visible to users less than 10k rep).

Comment: At 8 downvotes they just stop showing on the new list. Then it all depends on the users with enough rights. Some questions get closed, some get closed and soft deleted.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006 covers the other part besides when vanish from the front page. They can be automatically deleted without being closed in some cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the score of a question is lower than -3, the question is removed from the front page. Questions with many down-votes are still listed, and can be searched. You can search for [questions with a score greater or equal to -10](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?page=966&tab=relevance&q=votes:-10%20is:question).

There aren't automatically closed questions; there are questions that get automatically deleted but only in few cases, such as when the question has 6 flags for being spam or offensive, or it has a negative score and it doesn't have answers, once the question is at least one-month old. More recently, a change about deleting closed questions has been introduced, and it involve questions closed in the past 9 days, when:

The question was not closed as a duplicate
- It has a score of zero or less
- It is not locked
- It has no answers with a score higher than zero
- It has no accepted answer
- It has no pending reopen votes
- It has not been edited in the past nine days

Comment: Doesn't it take a score of *-4* before it is removed from the front page?

Comment: -4 on the main sites. -8 on meta.

Comment: Let's say lower than -3. `:)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno, in that case, they are still listed in the tags page

Comment: @ChicoSokol That is why I said, "are still listed." `:)`

Comment: You can even search for [questions with ≤ −10 score](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=votes%3A..-10+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: @icktoofay It is a shame that syntax is not explained in the advanced help for searching. `:|`

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Actually, with a recent change, [it now is explained](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching).